# Make properly formatted source code from function driven html

Tags: php, html, forms, oop

I have a method that is used to generate a user form from an array of properties.

The function works well for what I need, however when viewing the source code it is a continuous line, as opposed to the more readable indented format.

Here is the resulting source code:

```
<form><input name=songName type=text placeholder=Title </input><input name=songArtist type=text placeholder=Artist </input><input name=songGenre type=text placeholder=Genre </input><input name=year type=number placeholder=Year </input></form>
```

Here is what I'd like it to be:

```
<form>
    <input name=songName type=text placeholder=Title </input>
    <input name=songArtist type=text placeholder=Artist </input>
    <input name=songGenre type=text placeholder=Genre </input>
    <input name=year type=number placeholder=Year </input>
</form>
```

This is the final function which generates the html:

```
public function formGenerate($formElements)
{
    echo "<form>";

    foreach($formElements as $name=>$properties)            
    {
        echo "<input "."name=".$name." ";

        $propertiesArray    = explode('|',$properties);

        foreach($propertiesArray as $property)              
        {
            $split          = $this->splitPropertyAndValue($property);
            $propertyName   = $split['property'];
            $propertyValue  = $split['value'];

            echo $propertyName.'='.$propertyValue." ";
        }
        echo "</input>";
    }
    echo "</form>";
}
```

Here is an example of an array that is passed for $formElements:

```
$formElements = array
(
    'songName'      =>  'type:text|placeholder:Title',
    'songArtist'    =>  'type:text|placeholder:Artist',
    'songGenre'     =>  'type:text|placeholder:Genre',
    'year'          =>  'type:number|placeholder:Year'
);
```

Comment: fyi: input tags are self closing tags, anyway, do you have an example array value of `$formElements`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to add the corresponding indentation and newlines in your code like this:

```
public function formGenerate($formElements)
{
    echo "<form>\n";   // adding the \n for form

    foreach($formElements as $name=>$properties)            
    {
        echo "    <input "."name=".$name." ";

        $propertiesArray    = explode('|',$properties);

        foreach($propertiesArray as $property)              
        {
            $split          = $this->splitPropertyAndValue($property);
            $propertyName   = $split['property'];
            $propertyValue  = $split['value'];

            echo $propertyName.'='.$propertyValue." ";
        }
        echo ">\n"; // self closing tag!
    }
    echo "</form>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `\t` and `\n` in your echo statments... Play around with it and you'll get what you need :)